# I want use swiftdata (ryanfowler) for using sqlite in swift 2 but there is 120 errors ,what shouild i do?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, swift2, xcode7

i try using SwiftData  [1]: http://ryanfowler.github.io/SwiftData ,when import it to my project i have 120 errors that some of them is for println ,how i can resolved another errors?i add string extensions but errors still remains

Comment: i resolved other errors but now i have errors about sqlite3 (unresolved identifire sqlite3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the authors' git](https://github.com/ryanfowler/SwiftData) you can see that the last commit was a year ago; SwiftData is not Swift 2-compliant. E.g. the `println` error you see is because `println` was changed to `print` with the release of Swift 2. Unless you want to port SwiftData to Swift 2 yourself, you can't really resolve this in an easy manner.

However, it seems like an existing user has already had a look at this, see the the posts by user RegisStGelais in the following thread:

- [SwiftData: Update for Swift 2.1? - Issue #33](https://github.com/ryanfowler/SwiftData/issues/33)

For a complete Swift 2-updated version, see this fork by github user Lopdo:

- https://github.com/Lopdo/SwiftData

If interested in the changes performed from original SwiftData -> Swift 2-compatible, see [Lopdos commit](https://github.com/Lopdo/SwiftData/commit/c2183b730383c36cf1ff793591a75e0388f414cc).

---

Alternatively, have a look at a modified and extended Swift 2-ready version of SwiftData here:

- https://github.com/mozilla/firefox-ios/blob/master/Storage/ThirdParty/SwiftData.swift

> This is a heavily modified version of SwiftData.swift by Ryan Fowler
>
> This has been enhanced to support custom files, correct binding,
>   versioning, and a streaming results via Cursors. The API has also been
>   changed to use NSError, Cursors, and to force callers to request a
>   connection before executing commands. Database creation helpers,
>   savepoint helpers, image support, and other features have been
>   removed.